# Почему то строки не объединяюся в php

Tags: массивы, php, html, объединение, строки

```
function ShowTopMenu()
{
    $top_menu_captions = array("Главная", "Новости", "Гостевая", "О сайте");
    $top_menu_references = array("index.html", "#", "#", "#");
    global $active_menu_index;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $active_menu_str="\t\t\t<li class=\"top_menu_li\"";
        if ($i == $active_menu_index) {
            $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.' id="current_top_menu_li">';
            $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.$top_menu_captions[i];
        } else {
            $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.'><a href="';
            $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.$top_menu_references[i].'">';
            $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.$top_menu_captions[i]."</a>";
        }
        $active_menu_str = $active_menu_str."</li>\n";
        echo $active_menu_str;
    }
}

    Вот такой код состряпал. Когда вызываешь эту функцию со страницы index.html ("Главная"), $active_menu_index равно 0. У index.html должен быть такой код:

    ...
            <li class="top_menu_li" id="current_top_menu_li">Главная</li>
            <li class="top_menu_li"><a href="">Новости</a></li>
            <li class="top_menu_li"><a href="">Гостевая</a></li>
            <li class="top_menu_li"><a href="">О сайте</a></li>
    ...

    Вместо этого получается вот так:

    ...
                <li class="top_menu_li" id="current_top_menu_li"></li>
                <li class="top_menu_li"><a href=""></a></li>
                <li class="top_menu_li"><a href=""></a></li>
                <li class="top_menu_li"><a href=""></a></li>
    ...

    Почему не происходит сцепление строк $active_menu_str и $top_menu_captions[i], а между $active_menu_str и $top_menu_references[i] происходит? Уже битый час парюсь.

    P. S. index.html, и этот php файл, где находится этот файл сохранен в формате windows-1251. В index.html задана кодировка windows-1251.
    P. S. S. Пробовал массиву $top_menu_captions давать строки с английскими буквами и без спецсимволов и пробелов. Не помагает
```

Comment: И у вас не вылазит никакая ошибка в связи с такой записью?

   $top_menu_captions[i]; // Что такое "i"?

Comment: @Deonis я предполагаю, что там должно быть $i

Comment: @rnddev, тут и предполагать нечего, исходя из поставленной задачи и желаемого результата на выходе. Меня больше интересует ответ на мой риторический вопрос. Как можно делать отладку кода, когда нет вывода ошибок и предупреждений? Это всё равно, что звукооператор будет прослушивать аудио-запись, затыкая уши.

Comment: не проверяя отправляя на сайт файлы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$active_menu_str = $active_menu_str.' id="current_top_menu_li">';
```

Можно писать проще

```
$active_menu_str .= ' id="current_top_menu_li">';
```

Обратите внимание на точку перед оператором присваивания.